# Azure log analytics documentdb operations

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I have been attempting to create a chart based on a query that will return the different operations done on specific collections. I am only seeing "Read" in the OperationName column of AzureDiagnostics, I was expecting to see the inserts and updates/upserts that have been done on those collections.
Not sure if I am looking in the wrong place. 
Has anyone had any issues getting other operation names to be returned?

Sasha

Comment: Hello, just want to check if you can see the "update" in log analytics now?

Comment: Thanks Ivan, i was able to then see the update, however i got a strange response where the operationname was being displayed as UpdateUpdate, but we were able to update the display for the the graphs built from the query results, so it was not a big issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

1.In the "Diagnostic settings" of documentdb, make sure you checked all the checkboxes:

[image]

2.Then you can update an item, and make sure after change the content of item, you click the **Update** button:

[image]

3.Then in log analytics, you can use the query below to check if update is logged, remember to select a proper Time Range for the query:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

The OperationName **update** is there:

[image]